# Snap whole Item into full view upon scroll in a gridview

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I've got a GridView which displays images in a 1 row scrollable VirtualizingStackPanel. I'd like to be able to display the whole image when the user scrolls the thing and pauses in such a way that it's not 100% shown. Basically snap the item (image) into full view.

My code:

```
        <GridView 
            x:Name="m_acVideosView" Grid.Row="1" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserVideos, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Style="{StaticResource VideosGridView}" 
            ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" 
            SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

<Border>
<ScrollViewer x:Name="m_cVideosScroll"  
ManipulationCompleted="m_cVideosScroll_ManipulationCompleted"
ViewChanged="m_cVideosScroll_ViewChanged" >
</Border>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Tag="{Binding}" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"  
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="9"
                               Width="270" Height="480" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
```